# Mixing ternary operations and Eigen Arrays

Tags: c++, eigen, ternary-operator

I read in the Eigen docs (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Pit_Falls#Ternary_operator) that Eigen doesn't play nicely with ternary operations; that is certainly my experience.

What I am trying to do is to construct an array based on several boolean flags, the `use_XXX` flags in my snippet below.  I know that at least one of the flags is true from a check before, but I can't get this block to compile.  Here are other options that I have tried that don't work:

1. Construct the 2^4 = 16 logical options for `umat` using something like bit masks - the code ends up verbose and hard to maintain; yuck...
2. Initialize `umat` to zero, and then loop over the conditionals, doing inplace subtraction - this is quite a bit slower than the single sum when I manually comment out terms

Another idea was to try to multiply the expression by the flag, in the hopes that Eigen would use its template magic to figure out what to do, but that didn't work either, since in my case I don't initialize the array if I don't use it (very performance critical code in this loop)

```
umat = (
    (use_gauss_delta ? -coeffs.eta*delta_minus_epsilon.square() : 0)
    +
    (use_delta_ld ? -coeffs.cd*delta_to_ld : 0)
    +
    (use_gauss_tau ? -coeffs.beta*tau_minus_gamma.square() : 0)
    +
    (use_tau_lt ? -coeffs.ct*tau_to_lt : 0)
    )
);
```

**EDIT**

I also tried the `select` function, which works, but that is very slow.  Each of the mask_XXX are `Eigen::ArrayXi`, and all the others are `Eigen::ArrayXd`

```
umat = (
    mask_gauss_delta.select(-coeffs.eta*delta_minus_epsilon.square(),0)
    +
    mask_delta_ld.select(-coeffs.cd*delta_to_ld,0)
    +
    mask_gauss_tau.select(-coeffs.beta*tau_minus_gamma.square(),0)
    +
    mask_tau_lt.select(-coeffs.ct*tau_to_lt,0)
);
```

Comment: In the ternary statement `(<conditional> ? <true code> : <false code>)`, both `<true code>` and `<false code>` have to have the same type.  This is not just a curiosity of Eigen.  For example `(whatever ? 1.0 : "abc")` would also not work with the error `incompatible operand types ('double' and 'const char *')`.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your case it is impossible to say what types the operands have since you failed to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, sorry I know about the joys of non-MVE examples.  In the end, I went for the select solution.  It turned out to actually not be that much slower, thanks to Eigen's internal magic.

Comment: @HenriMenke - I was trying to upcast 0 into a zero-allocation Eigen object compatible with the ternary operator, and never did find an adequate solution.  I suspect there must be a way, but select works for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the type (as noted in the link you included in your question) to an `ArrayXd` (or whatever other object you're using) by adding `.eval()` to one condition. See example below:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

using Eigen::ArrayXd;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ArrayXd aa, res;
    int size = 6;
    aa.setLinSpaced(size, 0, 5);
    double d = 345.5;

    res = (true ? (d * aa.square()).eval() : ArrayXd::Zero(size));
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    res = (false ? (d * aa.square()).eval() : ArrayXd::Zero(size));
    std::cout << res << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

`d * aa.square()` is a `CwiseBinaryOp` where `ArrayXd::Zero(size)` is a `CwiseNullaryOp`, neither of which can be cast to the other. Adding `.eval()`  to one makes it an `ArrayXd` (and will create a temporary object, which it you seem not to want) and make the ternary operation work. However,

```
whatever = 
(true  ? (d * aa.square()).eval() : ArrayXd::Zero(size)) + 
(false ? (d * aa.square()).eval() : ArrayXd::Zero(size));
```

will still result in `ArrayXd::Zero(size)` being evaluated to a temporary, reducing performance. The option with the probably the best performance would be

```
if(use_gauss_delta) umat += -coeffs.eta*delta_minus_epsilon.square();
if(use_delta_ld)    umat += -coeffs.cd*delta_to_ld;
if(use_gauss_tau)   umat += -coeffs.beta*tau_minus_gamma.square();
if(use_tau_lt)      umat += -coeffs.ct*tau_to_lt;
```

The main disadvantage would be that the evaluation would happen up to four times, but without constructing the 2^4 options you mentioned, I can't think of a way to avoid that.

Comment: But in your ternary, that's not a no-op false condition, right?  This is really performance critical code, and I'm trying mightily to avoid allocation and copies

Comment: Then opt for the old fashion if-else statements. You can't have it both ways.